Git/Github novice help - repo per project or sub folder within main better?
I'm new to Git/Github - I have a project with multiple parts I'm working on across several servers.  I've been asked to put all my configs into my Github.
As it's the same project with multiple areas, is it better to have 1 repo with sub folders or separate repos?
Hello,
I'm using uDemy to learn Git/Github, it's great. I've a little confused on some areas, but I'll get there with practise. I'm going round in circles on this part.
I have a local folder I've initiated with:
git init -b main
the folder local looks like this:
/opt/docker$ ls
config  config.env  docker-compose.yml
I simple want to push it to my github into a sub folder called 'main/projectx'

At the moment it uploads to the root of main. The good thing it's all working with commit, push etc.
I'm not sure if this is a branch, but how can I get it to push to 'main/projectx'? projectx doesn't exist in my github main repo, I assumed locally I could push it to there and it would create it.
Any help would be great.
Thanks

Check out this question I hope this one fixes your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79199535/how-to-sync-a-specific-project-folder-from-my-website-to-my-remote-website-githu/79200080#79200080
